# box-align not working in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to set `box-align` to either `start` or `baseline` so that my columns will resize the way I want, but they won't stretch to be the same height, but this isn't working in Chrome of Firefox for some reason. It works fine in IE11.

Demo (shrink page to less than 1280px to see it take effect): http://www.weblinxinc.com/beta/hf-racquet-fitness-club/demo/site/internal.htm

Result in IE11:

[image]

Result in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: The browsers it's working in is interesting, given the browser compatibility table from it's [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-align) (which also mentions that `box-align` is part of a being-replaced standard, so you probably should stop using it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting the W3C's documentation, I discovered there's a property `align-items`, which solved my problem:

```
-webkit-flex-align: baseline;
-webkit-align-items: baseline;
-ms-flex-align: baseline;
align-items: baseline;
```